# Record/copies of PHP mail() previously sent from our website?

Tags: php, email, web

Should there be a record of all php sent mail (via our hosts mail() function) anywhere?

Our web developer made an oversight and all enquiries sent via the our host's (godaddy.com) mailer relay for the last 2 months were rejected by our local mail server. Naturally, our server doesn't keep any rejected emails.

I have spoken to godaddy.com and they claim there is no record, however I'm not particularly confident with the answer.

Is there anything I can do? The enquiry form is now fixed (used Mandrill), so that's not an issue.

Comment: The answer is unfortunately still no. `mail()` sends emails, if you want them logged, you'd have to explicitly set that up.

Comment: Log the body and mail details to your DB before sending out the message. That would be the only way unless you BCC a storage mailbox onto every message.

Comment: Sendmail or Postfix may log that a message was sent, including the from and to address; you won't be able to get more than that, and that will be limited by the configuration and how often logs are rotated. I'd be inclined to believe GoDaddy when they say they have nothing useful.

Comment: You can also try examining your apache logs. Depending on where the failure occurred, this might have been logged. If you're using purely `mail()` it's not going to do much for you.

Comment: Pretty much as I feared. Thanks for all your comments, I'll resign myself to having an unpleasant conversation with the developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the mails are gone now.

Rejected mails that a mail server tried to send usually go to the mail admin account of the sending server as a bounce - however, even that account might not be set up or failing or rejecting mail, so the mail server will get rid of these undeliverable mails that double-bounced by deleting them from the queue.

You might get an idea of what was tried to mail if you are able to get your hand onto a mail server logfile, but assuming this is in the hands of your hosting provider, your chances are low: 1. these logs would only give you an idea of which mail addresses were involved, but no content. 2. the log files usually get deleted quickly because they'd serve no regular purpose.

Comment: Pretty much as I feared. Thanks for all your comments, I'll resign myself to having an unpleasant conversation with the developer.